# Home page redirection in Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, url

My wesite make a redirection from the home page to the Group Deals page with my magento 1.8 when the URL is http://www.example.com/

But when the URL is https://www.example.com/ or http://.example.com/ the redirection didn't work.

How can I make it work with the last 2 URLs

Thank you in advance

This is the redirect part in .htaccess:

> RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteRule ^(.+).(\d+).(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ $1.$3 [L]
>   RewriteRule ^(typo3/|t3lib/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads> > >  > /|favicon.ico) - [L]
>   RewriteRule ^typo3$ typo3/index_re.php [L]
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
>   RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

Comment: sounds like something done in the `.htaccess`. If you can check for that and post the redirect part with your question we can help you

Comment: I add the redirect part

Comment: This looks like the htaccess of a Typo3 installation. That might be interfering  with the Magento code.